# where needed to create file to read from it in android

Tags: android, file

I can't create a file.

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "info.txt";
File f = new File(FILE_NAME);
if(f.exists()){
    Log.d("My Error", "exists");
}else{
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("My Error", "can't create");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in logs it printed my Log "My Error" with "can't create"

what i must do else? and where file will be created?

Comment: What are the exception details?

Comment: First of all where do you want to create file? in a SD card or in internal storage.?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a file that your application can write to and then later read from, use `openFileOutput()` like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, 0);
```

This will create a file in the application's private data directory. Only your application can read/write to this directory.